# Other keywords are not allowed when the 'Name' keyword is specified

Tags: linqpad

I get the error in the title when I try to run a query in Linqpad, v4.43.06

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

mmm nevermind, this has to do with the EF context definition in the DLL I am connecting to.

Comment: Rather than self answer it might be better just to delete this question.